# jQuery - submit() fires multiple times. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I have a form that on `submit` the following code is executed

```
$(document).on('submit','#search_client_form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clientSearch();
});

function clientSearch(){
   console.log('foo')
}
```

I can see in the console that the word foo is executed **11** or **12** times rather **1**.

I have manage to solve my problem by adding the `off()` function before the `on()` on my first code sample.

What i need, is an explanation of why this is happening. In previous development i have never experienced the same issue.

**UPDATE:**

My form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::open(array('id' => 'search_client_form')) }}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_client_term" placeholder="Search For Client">
        <span class="input-group-btn text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"> Search</i>
            </button>
        </span>
        {{Form::close()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `return false;` in the event handler

Comment: This happens because, the `on` method add a listener, it do not replace already existing listeners. you may have called `.on` multiple times

Comment: @Tushar why return false when `e.preventDefault` ?

Comment: @Hacketo Maybe, event propagation

Comment: @Hacketo Maybe if i replace the `on()` with `click()` ?

Comment: @Makis you can't because you're using event delegation

Comment: @Tushar propagation would not fire the same handler multiple times. It would fire a parent listener

Comment: @Makis is that the entire code? are you sure you're not accidentally attaching the handler inside of a loop or something like that?

Comment: cross check : did you suplied any form action or onsubmit event in form itself ?

Comment: @Makis `click(` does the same thing as `on('click'` , the  only difference is that you can't do `off('click'` if you use the first one

Comment: @billyonecan Yes, absolutely sure, there is nothing but an `html form`. Thats the reason why i can't find the solution..!

Comment: @Makis can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle? It works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mt23xmuh/)

Comment: @Nishith Not at all. Only an id.

Comment: @billyonecan Yes i see, thats weird. I cannot reproduce the code because i'm using Laravel's templating system. I will Update the post and add the form's code right now.

Comment: adding `onclick` on the submit button should fix this.. but don't know why this one is going wrong?